# AssertionError: labels.txt and cfg/yolov2.cfg indicate inconsistent class numbers

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, labelimg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kmpg.jpg)
I had already modify label.txt & tiny-yolo.cfg
but it still show up
AssertionError: labels.txt and cfg/yolov2.cfg indicate inconsistent class numbers

Answer (score 0):

First i see you have tiny-yolo.cfg and yolov2.cfg, it looks like you have modified tiny-yolo.cfg but your code is running the old file yolov2.cfg.

You usually get this error when trying to train a model but your labels.txt and cfg are not compatible. Download new, or edit a new copy of the cfg file and try again.  remember to leave the original in the same folder.